# Downfill incremetation skip 2 columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I'm trying do create a master sheet for work, as for nom we work in the middle age, copying some data to up to 4 differents documents and I want that to change :D

I'm quite new to Excel (more than basics I mean), and I have a problem that I can't seem to find a solution online.
My sheets are as follow :

[image: simplified version]

So in Sheet one, C5 i want the result for sheet 2 E16, but in sheet 1 D5, I want the result for H16.

When I try to use downfill, it doesn't understand that I want to get the results while skipping everytime 2 columns between the results in sheet 2.

The cells are blank in the other cells in Sheet2 row 4, so i would guess there could  be some conditionning possible, with a function like isblank, but I'm struggling to understand how I could do it.

Any help?

Thanks a lot for reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!E16:16; MOD(COLUMN(Sheet2!E16:16)+1; 3)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, @player0 I doesnt seem to work :/
I tried the code, and it gives me an error message. I've had that a few times trying codes others shared with me, that worked with them but not with me. I 've checked the syntax and all but doesn't seem to be a problem there

Comment: @MathiasGilles answer updated.. try now. if it still wont work share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: Yes!! It works :)) You can't know how happy I am, that is going to be such a useful tool :D
Thank you heeps!

Comment: @MathiasGilles if the answer solved your question, feel free not to mark it as solved - this way, maybe someone will provide a better solution

Comment: Sorry, looked for how to mark one as answerd in here and couldn't find :)